# Optimizing query mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in which i store some values. Everything is working fine except my query is taking too long to execute. I have around 500.000 rows in table "tickets" at the moment. I would like to know what would be the best way to optimize this query to execute SELECT faster.

One more thing: I would like to know is there a way to update all rows through query (not using my C# app). In this case i need to update column "wonamount" which is in tickets with value that i get by multiplying row "coefficient" with row "uplata" and update column status with value "2".

Here are my tables and sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coefficients` (`number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`coefficient` int(11) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `coefficients` (`number`, `coefficient`) VALUES
(1, 0),
(2, 0),
(3, 0),
(4, 0),
(5, 0),
(6, 10000),
(7, 7500),
(8, 5000),
(9, 2500),
(10, 1000),
(11, 500),
(12, 300),
(13, 200),
(14, 120),
(15, 80),
(16, 70),
(17, 60),
(18, 50),
(19, 40),
(20, 35),
(21, 30),
(22, 25),
(23, 20),
(24, 15),
(25, 12),
(26, 10),
(27, 9),
(28, 8),
(29, 7),
(30, 6),
(31, 5),
(32, 4),
(33, 3),
(34, 2),
(35, 1);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `draws` (
`iddraws` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`3` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`4` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`5` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`6` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`7` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`8` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`9` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`10` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`11` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`12` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`13` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`14` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`15` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`16` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`17` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`18` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`19` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`20` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`21` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`22` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`23` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`24` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`25` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`26` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`27` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`28` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`29` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`30` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`31` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`32` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`33` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`34` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`35` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`datetime` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`iddraws`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=162 ;


INSERT INTO `draws` (`iddraws`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`, `16`, `17`, `18`, `19`, `20`, `21`, `22`, `23`, `24`, `25`, `26`, `27`, `28`, `29`, `30`, `31`, `32`, `33`, `34`, `35`, `datetime`) VALUES
(1, '17', '46', '27', '30', '8', '11', '4', '40', '37', '36', '22', '14', '35', '47', '24', '20', '23', '10', '2', '42', '41', '43', '9', '19', '7', '48', '3', '38', '29', '44', '16', '12', '26', '13', '5', '1391130262'),
(2, '45', '2', '1', '24', '30', '4', '10', '11', '22', '3', '38', '33', '35', '14', '48', '28', '42', '27', '43', '9', '15', '29', '36', '41', '26', '23', '13', '5', '16', '20', '12', '6', '32', '37', '19', '1391134904'),
(3, '12', '46', '32', '15', '14', '41', '45', '6', '9', '20', '26', '2', '47', '37', '33', '39', '34', '17', '16', '23', '35', '29', '44', '36', '18', '40', '22', '4', '27', '30', '38', '21', '3', '43', '24', '1391135221');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (
`id_tiketa` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idtickets` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`b1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`b2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`b3` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`b4` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`b5` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`b6` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`shop` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`user` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`time` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`uplata` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`draw` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`qt` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`wonamount` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_tiketa`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=138 ;


INSERT INTO `tickets` (`id_tiketa`, `idtickets`, `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`, `b5`, `b6`, `shop`, `user`, `time`, `status`, `uplata`, `draw`, `qt`, `wonamount`) VALUES
(75, '4-1-170-1367', '41', '47', '17', '24', '15', '44', '170', 'w1', '1391149398', '1', '1', '1', '', ''),
(76, '4-1-170-20104', '23', '27', '13', '7', '14', '42', '170', 'w1', '1391149398', '1', '1', '1', '', ''),
(91, '4-2-170-13887', '16', '4', '13', '35', '30', '9', '170', 'w1', '1391149462', '1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(92, '4-2-170-9701', '2', '32', '7', '15', '5', '34', '170', 'w1', '1391149463', '1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(93, '4-2-170-45661', '23', '24', '22', '27', '48', '6', '170', 'w1', '1391149463', '1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(98, '4-2-170-45503', '36', '13', '33', '10', '29', '9', '170', 'w1', '1391149463', '1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(99, '4-2-170-24095', '19', '35', '11', '36', '46', '40', '170', 'w1', '1391149463', '1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(100, '4-2-170-42832', '27', '32', '17', '29', '7', '21', '170', 'w1', '1391149463', '1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(101, '4-2-170-13570', '22', '23', '32', '6', '1', '28', '170', 'w1', '1391149463', '1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(103, '4-2-170-28122', '15', '10', '11', '9', '14', '48', '170', 'w1', '1391149463', '1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(116, '4-2-170-13095', '28', '20', '33', '42', '26', '14', '170', 'w1', '1391149464', '1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(118, '4-2-170-27646', '23', '14', '37', '27', '24', '19', '170', 'w1', '1391149464', '1', '1', '2', '', ''),
(124, '4-2-170-23302', '20', '23', '15', '38', '4', '45', '170', 'w1', '1391149465', '1', '1', '2', '', '');







SELECT t.idtickets,
       t.uplata,
       c.coefficient
FROM tickets t
INNER JOIN draws d ON(FIELD(t.b1,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
AND (FIELD(t.b2,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
AND (FIELD(t.b3,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
AND (FIELD(t.b4,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
AND (FIELD(t.b5,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
AND (FIELD(t.b6,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0)
INNER JOIN coefficients c ON c.number = GREATEST(FIELD(t.b1,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35), FIELD(t.b2,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35), FIELD(t.b3,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35), FIELD(t.b4,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35), FIELD(t.b5,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35), FIELD(t.b6,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35))
WHERE t.draw='1'
  AND t.status = '1'
  AND d.iddraws='1'
```

And yes, i need to do that for each t.draw and d.iddraws which will be same values.

Comment: Please put the relevant code in your post as well.

Comment: I would but my query is too large to post here so i posted my tables and query in this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaf7c8/1)

Comment: You can put your `CREATE TABLE` codes to the post. I've already formatted your SELECT statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While my answer is fairly general, I am assuming you are using MySQL.

**Short Answer:**
Do the following things one by one in the order mentioned while measuring performance improvement with each step.

1. Add Indexes on `tickets.draw` and `tickets.status`. Also add an `index` (`primary key` will be even better) on `coefficients.number`.
2. Use int instead of varchar wherever possible.
3. Convert `query` to  `stored procedure` to save values of `FIELD` calls and reuse these values in `GREATEST` instead of calling `FIELD` again with same values.
4. Move calls to `FIELD` at `INSERT`/`UPDATE` time instead of `SELECT`.

Yes, you can update all rows through query. Use your `SELECT` query and make the following changes to it:

1. Replace `SELECT t.idtickets,t.uplata, c.coefficient FROM` by `UPDATE`
2. Add `SET t.wonamount = c.coefficient*t.uplata, t.status='2'` before `WHERE ...`

**(Really) Long Answer:**
Your question is a very good case for discussing SQL optimization as there are many optimization techniques that can be applied here. Let me discuss them in **increasing order of complexity**, so that you can implement them one by one till you are happy with the results. I will also generalize every point for community's benefit while giving precise suggestions to you. Let's start:

1. All `SQL` optimization starts with `EXPLAIN`. It's a sort of black magic that tells what's wrong with your query. Simply add the `EXPLAIN` keyword before the `SELECT` keyword in your query and you get a wealth of information on how your query is executed behind the scene. Here is the `EXPLAIN` output of your query (some fields removed for sake of brevity):

   ```
   +-------+-------+---------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------+    
   | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | ref   | rows | Extra           |    
   +-------+-------+---------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------+    
   | d     | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | const |    1 |                 |    
   | t     | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL  |   13 | Using where     |    
   | c     | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL  |   35 | Using where;... |    
   +-------+-------+---------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------+
   ```

   Each row covers a `table` involved in your query. Two important fields to look at here are `key` and `rows`. `rows` tells the number of rows of that table scanned for the query. The more this number, the more data `MySQL` has to scan, and therefore the slower your query. `key` tells if `MySQL` is using any shortcut to reduce `rows`. In the absence of any `key`, `MySQL` has to scan all rows of that `table`. So, we need to supply `keys` (also called `indexes`) to `MySQL` so that it can reduce `rows` and execute queries fast.

   - Here, table `t` (i.e. `tickets`) is not using any `key` and therefore scanning all rows (there are 13 rows in the sample data you provided in your fiddle, and 500,000 of them in the real data). So, we add `keys` (or `indexes`) to those fields of `tickets` table that are involved in decision making in this query. These fields are `draw` and `status` (... `WHERE t.draw='1' AND t.status = '1'`...).

     - mysql> `ALTER TABLE tickets ADD INDEX idx_draw(draw);`
     - mysql> `ALTER TABLE tickets ADD INDEX idx_status(status);`
   - Similarly, `coefficients` will benefit by index on `number`. A `PRIMARY KEY` on `number` will be even better if `number`s are unique.
2. Integer data types (`short`, `int`, `long`, etc.) are significantly faster than character data types (`char`, `varchar`, etc.). So, avoid using character data types for integer data. In your data, all fields in `draws` table, and almost all fields in `tickets` table contain numeric data. (Booleans can be stored as `byte` instead of `varchar`. Also consider storing timestamps as `int` or `long` instead of `varchar`.)
3. `FIELD` is a costly call, especially if given a lot of arguments, as has to do a lot of work. In your query there are six distinct `FIELD` calls, and each is repeated in the call to `GREATEST` function, making 12 calls in total. Consider using `stored procedures` which allow you to save results of function calls in variables and reuse them later.
4. Performing validations during `INSERT`/`UPDATE` is better than performing them during `SELECT`. Consider validating your `tickets.b1-b6` against `draws.1-35` while inserting/updating instead of querying and your `SELECT` query will be much simpler and faster. The result of `GREATEST` can also be calculated at insert/update time and saved in an extra field in the `tickets` table to avoid recalculation every time during `SELECT`.

As with all queries, your query may need more optimizations when your data grows 100-1000 times its current size, but these should be enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

does your db have indexes?
[MYSQL indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)